# Jenkins, Gradle, clean works but compileJava fails (Permission Denied)

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, permissions

I am new to Jenkins and I would like to use it for my gradle project. I downloaded the gradle plugins for Jenkins, but when i try to build my app, I got

```
Building in workspace /home/alexi/Documents/workspace/testJenkins
[Gradle] - Launching build.
[testJenkins] $ /home/alexi/Documents/workspace/testJenkins/gradlew clean build test
:clean UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/alexi/Documents/workspace/testJenkins/.gradle/2.13/taskArtifacts/cache.properties.lock (Permission denied)
> /home/alexi/Documents/workspace/testJenkins/.gradle/2.13/taskArtifacts/cache.properties.lock (Permission denied)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.147 secs
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have tried to put chmod 777 to the .gradle directory, but I still got this error.

In my build steps, I have a new gradle step where I use the `Gradle Wrapper` and then `make gradlew executable`, I also check the field `From Root Build Script Dir`. The tasks I am executing are `clean build test`

Also, when I run those commands in Spring Tools SUite /Eclipse, it works perfectly, my Jenkins is on localhost

Comment: can you run a simple shell command through Jenkins to mkdir on that same path?

Comment: Thanks for answering, Indeed I can create a directory using mkdir but I add to uncheck the `make gradlew executable` checkbox

Comment: My bad, I didn't add to uncheck the box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to remove the .gradle file already existing in my project (created with Spring Boot)